# IReadOnlyCollection with notifications

Tags: c#, collections

It is not related to GUI. I have a class with:

1. Private `List`, which is edited inside the class.
2. Open `IReadOnlyCollection` property for access to private `List`
3. Public `event` for notification on `List` changing

A list stores objects with properties. The class can changed an item's properties and notify about it. The user can only read an item's properties. I only picked this option.

```
class MortarInfo
{
    public double Angle { get; private set; }
    public bool State { get; private set; }
    public MortarInfo(double angle, bool state)
    {
        Angle = angle;
        State = state;
    }
}
class Mortars
{
    private List<MortarInfo> _mortarsInfo;
    private ReadOnlyCollection<MortarInfo> _readOnlyMortarsInfo;

    public Mortars()
    {
        _mortarsInfo = new List<MortarInfo>();
        _readOnlyMortarsInfo = _mortarsInfo.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<MortarInfo> MortarsInfo
    {
        get { return _readOnlyMortarsInfo; }
    }
    public event ListChangedEventHandler MortarsInfoChanged;

    public void UpdateAngle(int index, double newAngle)
    {
        if (_mortarsInfo[index].Angle != newAngle)
        {
            _mortarsInfo[index] = new MortarInfo(newAngle, _mortarsInfo[index].State);
            if (MortarsInfoChanged != null)
            {
                var arg = new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemChanged, index);
                MortarsInfoChanged(this, arg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems good but I have some comments on this,

1. Why do you create a new ListItem in every property change and not just replace to old property with the new one?

   ```
   _list[index].Property1 = property1;
   ```
2. You raise the event without null check. Do this:

   ```
   var listChanged = ListChanged;
   if (listChanged != null)
       listChanged(this,new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemChanged, index));
   ```
3. As a side note, if Property1 or Property2 are complex objects, It's recommended to create for them you own equal methods (`Equal`, `GetHashCode`, `==` and `!=`). If the are generic, implement `IEquatable<T>`

Comment: 1. I create a new ListItem, because user don't to be able to hange anything.
2. In project i use Extension methods to raise event. It have a check.
3. It a good idea.

Comment: It'd be helpful to explain why the temporary variable is needed in the null check. I.e. The handler could go null between the check and call without it.